# get a specific value of a C # XML node

Tags: c#, xml

i have a this fuction where load mi xml, search nodes BUT...

xml:

```
<Shipment>
     <DataContext>
      <DataSourceCollection>
        <DataSource>
          <Type>FShipment</Type>
          <Key>XX123456</Key>
          <Date>2019-12-19</Date>
        </DataSource>
      </DataSourceCollection>
      <Company>
        <Code>NTL</Code>
        <Country>
          <Code>MX</Code>
          <Name>Mexico</Name>
        </Country>
        <Name>RTYC SA DE CV</Name>
      </Company>

      <FinalDestination>
        <Code>NTLC</Code>
        <Country>
          <Code>MX</Code>
          <Name>Mexico</Name>
        </Country>
        <Name>BODEGA COATEPEC</Name>
      </FinalDestination>
</Shipment>
```

my code:

```
 XmlDocument midocxml = new XmlDocument();
            midocxml.Load(@"C:\test\TYC.xml");
XmlNodeList nodoValueGoods = midocxml.GetElementsByTagName("Company");

            foreach (XmlElement nodo9 in nodoValueGoods)
            {

                foreach (XmlElement nodo9Value in nodo9.GetElementsByTagName("Code"))
                   MessageBox.Show(nodo9Value.InnerText.ToString());// <---when show values and click,change.. i need define what result do i want to show
 }
```

when I execute my function, if I get the values ​​of the node, but if I press accept it changes the value, will there be a way where the result can define if I want the value 1 or 2?
show image where explain problem with button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad8m8.png)

help me pls

Comment: Since you are using `foreach` loop, a value on the message box is changed. btw, What would you like to show on the message box? Plz explain your expectations clearly.

Comment: your `GetElementsByTagName("Company")` returned one node. Then you call `GetElementsByTagName("Code")` for this node, which returns two entries: the "NTL" which is a direct child, and "MX" which is a nested child. Maybe thats what confuses you? If you only want to see the child, call `nodo9.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.Tagname == "Code")` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I am not using linq, and if I want to get specific result, foreach example (XmlElement node9Value in node9.GetElementsByTagName ("Code"))
                   MessageBox.Show (node9Value [0] .InnerText.ToString ());//show NTL
MessageBox.Show (node9Value [1] .InnerText.ToString ());//show MX

will it be possible?